# Small images getting behind the left module of the web site product page

Tags: css, image, macos, z-index, joomla1.5

On my web site's product page I do have small images that link to big images those small images are on the left side and visiable on windows with chrome, firefox and safari. [product page](http://www.sohoconcept.com/products/sofas/boston-sofa)

However, those small images getting behind the left module when MAC used with chrome and safari.What should be the problem? I am having very big trouble with this issue.

Please suggest a way. Thank you.